# Convert `=> Unit` to `() => Unit`

Tags: scala, lambda

What is type of this block: `callback: => Unit`?

How I can assign it to `Option`? In other words how to update following code so it doesn't have any compilation errors?

```
  var onEventCallback: Option[() => Unit] = None

  def onEvent(callback: => Unit) {
    onEventCallback = Some(callback)  // HERE compilation error: Some[Unit] doesn't conform to Option[() => Unit] 
  }
```

**Ok. I solved it using `Some(callback _)` instead of `Some(callback)`. But why this work?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler needs to know whether you want callback to be executed immediately or not. WIthout the underscore immediate execution is assumed, and the result is assigned to the Some. WIth the underscore, the compiler knows that it shouldn't execute callback to get the result but should treat it as the parameter to pass to the Some constructor (or rather, apply() method).

Answer (score 3):

> But why this work?

Sometimes you can think of `by-name` parameter as a function without arguments. Actually it is a `Function0` after `erasure` phase in compiler. You could compile you code with `-Xprint:erasure` to see this:

```
def onEvent(callback: Function0): Unit = onEventCallback_=(new Some(callback))
```